# MySQL query extreme slow filtering on CASE WHEN formula

Tags: mysql, alias

Using MySQL 5.6 i encounter a big performance problem when filtering on a calculated formula using conditions with `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` syntax.

This SQL formula is mapped by Hibernate.
Around 6000 rows in database.
Table `foo` has indices on columns `product` and `barcode`

**1. slow 2-16 s**

```
select 
    count(*)
from 
    foo AS f
where 
    (
        CASE WHEN f.product IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE (
            CASE WHEN f.barcode IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE  (
                SELECT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM product AS p
                    WHERE p.barcode = f.barcode
                    LIMIT 1
                )
            ) END
        ) END
    ) = 0
```

`EXPLAIN` results:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+-----+---------+-----+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
| id |    select_type     | table | type |         possible_keys         | key | key_len | ref | rows  |                       Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+-----+---------+-----+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | f     | ALL  |                               |     |         |     |   700 | Using where                                       |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p     | ALL  | UQ_product,IX_product_barcode |     |         |     |  3134 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2008) |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+-----+---------+-----+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**2. fast ~ 0.4 s**

```
select 
    *
from 
    foo AS f
where 
    (CASE ... END) = 0
```

`EXPLAIN` results identical to count query.

Comment: Please identify what you are removing.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should probably try to look at the output of `EXPLAIN` to garner more information.

But either way, let's try cleaning up your query a bit and see if we can't make use of a few indexes. The biggest smell is the`CASE xxx = 0`; I wonder if the query parser is having trouble making an efficient plan and is calculating this value per row and comparing the result to 0.

So let's rewrite this as:

```
where f.product is null
and (
    f.barcode is null 
    or exists (select 1 from product p where p.barcode = f.barcode)
)
```

If this does not fix the problem, try updating your index statistics with [`ANALYZE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html).

Comment: Using `EXPLAIN` on both queries gives identical results except the first one obviously uses a `WHERE` clause. In my case i cannot rewrite the query as you suggest since I am using an ORM framework to map the formula, so I have no access to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hmm, can you post your explain results then?

Comment: It seems it is related to column `barcode` which uses `utf8_general_ci `. When i remove barcode comparison it runs very quick.

Comment: I dropped and recreated the Index on the `barcode` columns and now it is as fast as supposed.